# Specify a controller to main.gsp layout

Tags: grails

I know I can specify a controller for root page using `"/"(controller: "default")` in UrlMappings.groovy, however I would like to make my main layout page (in that case is main.gsp) to access at least one defined controller. I've tried `"/layouts/main.gsp"(controller: "default")` but didn't work. How can I accomplish it? Thanks!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found another way to fix my issue. Now I can pass user instance that is comming from session for every action. So every time and everywhere my layout header shows the user information (if user is logged on, of course).

My steps:

1. First of all, create a grails filter;
2. Modify your "after" clousure from the filter created
   to get current user and pass it through to every controller's action, it suppose to be something like that:

   ```
   after = { Map model ->

       def user = null

       if (!session.isNew()) {
           user = session["user"]

           if (user) {
               if (!model)
                   model = [:]

               model["user"] = user
           }
       }

   }
   ```

I hope it can be helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

`main.gsp` is a layout and not a page. layouts are used by pages which are rendered by controllers. You should not have design that makes controllers render a layout. It destroys the beautiful structure of Grails. 
If you want to access an object in that layout, then you pass the object to the page that uses the layout.
Tell us about your use case and we might be able to help you a little more.

Comment: Thanks Johri. I would like to get access to my User instance that I put to session everywhere. So I thought it would be a good way through. But please, let me know another better way to accomplish it.